# How do I programmatically open the "Libraries" folder in Windows Explorer in Windows 7?

Tags: .net, windows-7, windows-shell

Note, the user may have redefined the default window for windows explorer, so simply opening "" using `Process.Start` or `IShellDispatch.Open` is not going to be acceptable.

I figured this would be trivial, but I've lost a day trying to find an example.  Note, the Libraries folder is a known folder with a folder id of `FOLDERID_Libraries`.  Opening up using the associated GUID for `FOLDERID_Libraries` using

`Process.Start("explorer.exe", "::{1B3EA5DC-B587-4786-B4EF-BD1DC332AEAE}")`

opened "My Documents" instead.

While VB.NET or C# would be preferred, I can engineer a solution from almost any language.

Many thank,

Tom

Comment: have you tried simply using Windows-Run `shell:Libraries` Just tried this in a command prompt too.
`explorer shell:libraries` opened what I expected

Comment: It worked.  Could you make it an answer so I can award it to you?

Comment: Also, if you have it off hand, do you know of a pointer to a list of the "shell:" objects.  Google didn't show up much for "Shell:Libraries" and "Shell:" site:microsoft.com was too general...

Comment: Never mind the reference, I found http://rainmeter.net/cms/Tips-LaunchSpecialFolders.  Thanks again for the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried simply using Windows-Run `shell:Libraries` Just tried this in a command prompt too. `explorer shell:libraries` opened what I expectedI don't kn

Comment: Successful used in
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open("shell:Libraries")
Also works with a large number of other special folders as documented at <http://rainmeter.net/cms/Tips-LaunchSpecialFolders> (look down the page).

Comment: Try 2: 
Successfuly used in
    `CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open("shell:Libraries")`
Also works with a large number of other special folders as documented at http://rainmeter.net/cms/Tips-LaunchSpecialFolders (look down the page for shell names split by OS).