# AUTOIT: How to expand a treeview in an existing application?

Tags: autoit

For example is My Computer. How to automate the expanding of the "Computer" tree?

```
#include <GuiTreeView.au3>
Run("C:")
WinWaitActive("My Computer")
$hTreeView = "SysTreeView32"
_GUICtrlTreeView_Expand($hTreeView)
```

Comment: In your code `$hTreeView` is not a handle, it's just a String. You should use [ControlGetHandle](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlGetHandle.htm) to retrieve a handle of the TreeView: `$hTreeView = ControlGetHandle('[CLASS:CabinetWClass]', '', 'SysTreeView321')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update :**

You can run *shell:MyComputerFolder* command which will take you right to My Computer :
http://winaero.com/blog/the-full-list-of-shell-commands-in-windows-8/

Finally you can run *explorer.exe /e,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}* which will take you right to MyComputer : http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/51661-make-explorer-start-with-my-computer/

---

When you open C:\ you can send ALT+Up which will take you to My Computer.

See this as well : [How do I programmatically open the "Libraries" folder in Windows Explorer in Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943083/how-do-i-programmatically-open-the-libraries-folder-in-windows-explorer-in-win)